# How to make an EditorGUILayout.TextField accept multi-line input in a custom inspector

Tags: unity, c#, editors

In a regular inspector:

```
[TextArea(4, 100)] [SerializeField] private string message;
```

Will expand a text field and let it accept multiple lines, with enter as opposed to needing \n. On the other hand:

```
script.message = EditorGUILayout.TextField(
                      "Message: ",
                      script.message,
                      GUILayout.Height(80));
```

Will also expand the text field, but does not allow for multiple line input. How can I get my custom inspector to behave the same way as the regular one and accept multi-line input?

Comment: Have you tried `EditorGUILayout.TextArea`?

Comment: That's very different from a TextField. PropertyField works better.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so this works as an alternative:

`EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(message, GUILayout.Height(80));`

Comment: Hello Jeff, and welcome to GameDev SE. Your answer is good, but it seems a bit short. We think you could expand it and describe how it is addressing the starting problem, so that more users may find it useful for similar issues :)

Answer (score 1):

You can preempt your `EditorGUILayout.TextArea()` with `EditorStyles.textField.wordWrap = true`

[image]

That looks like this in my CustomEditor.cs file:

```
if (info != String.Empty)
{
    showConstructorInfo = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showConstructorInfo, "Constructor Information");
    if (showConstructorInfo)
    {
        EditorStyles.textField.wordWrap = true; // This sets the wordwrap value of the property
        EditorGUILayout.TextArea(info);
    }
}
```

I have a bit more about how I'm doing some custom inspector stuff on my blog here: https://www.labyrintheer.com/2021/10/01/unity-custom-attributes-and-custom-editors/.

I plan to write a bit more about custom inspector and custom scene view stuff as I get this project wrapped up.